# Trying to generate a data frame in a for loop

Tags: r

Currently I'm working on the following code:

```
data <- rep(1:3, times = c(10,4,6))
for(i in 1:5) {
  samp <- sample(data, 4)
  data <- exclude(data, samp)
  print(samp)

  for(i in 1:3) {
        prsamp <- sum(samp == i)/4
        print(prsamp)
  }

  if (length(data) == 0) {
        break
  }
}
```

This currently prints out five vectors of length four, with the corresponding probabilities of each number occurring in each vector.

```
> source("buffoon.R")
> buffoon(20, 4, 3, c(10,4,6))
[1] 1 1 2 3
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 1 3 3 2
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.5
[1] 2 1 1 1
[1] 0.75
[1] 0.25
[1] 0
[1] 3 1 2 3
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.5
[1] 1 3 1 1
[1] 0.75
[1] 0
[1] 0.25
```

So, for instance, the first vector 1123 gives us a 0.5 prob of 1, 0.25 of 2, and 0.25 of 3. I would like to turn the output into a nice data frame which lists in column 1 each row vector, and in column 2 another row vector corresponding to the respective elemental probability occurrences, but I'm running into many errors. I've been researching this issue for a few hours now, but no success. Any help is appreciated.

My ideal data frame would look like this:

```
     Sample        Probability Dist
1    1123          0.5 0.25 0.25
2    1332          0.25 0.25 0.5
```

and so on, down to row 5.

Comment: Which package is the `exclude` function from?

Comment: `exclude <- function(from, where) {
      for (i in where)
            if (i %in% from) {
                  from = from[-match(i, from)]
            };
      from
}`

Comment: it's a function that removes submultisets from multisets basically

Comment: Show us how your final vectors look like, and how your output should look like. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you will have to do is create an empty dataframe. Secondly, you will want your for loop to write in this dataframe instead of simply printing out the results directly. Also, you don't want to use a for loop containing i as variable in a for loop already using i. I suggest you try the following:

```
data <- rep(1:3, times = c(10,4,6))
datafr <- data.frame(Sample=rep(NA,5),Probability.Dist=rep(NA,5))
for(i in 1:5) {
  samp <- sample(data, 4)
  data <- exclude(data, samp)
  datafr$Sample[i] <- samp[1]*1000+samp[2]*100+samp[3]*10+samp[4] #easy way of getting your wanted sample layout

  prsamp <- rep(0,3)
  for(j in 1:3) {
        prsamp[j] <- sum(samp == j)/4
  }
  datafr$Probability.Dist[i] <- toString(prsamp)

  if (length(data) == 0) {
        break
  }
}
datafr
#  Sample Probability.Dist
#1   1231  0.5, 0.25, 0.25
#2   2132  0.25, 0.5, 0.25
#3   1313      0.5, 0, 0.5
#4   2111    0.75, 0.25, 0
#5   3131      0.5, 0, 0.5
```

I also have to advise you against using 3 values in a single column of a dataframe. For further analysis and even readability, it would be much preferred to give each value it's own column.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give your advice a listen. By the way, suppose I wanted to generalize `samp[1]*1000+samp[2]*100+samp[3]*10+samp[4]` to a dot product of `(1,10,100, ... , 10^(n-1))` and `(samp[1], ... , samp[n])`? How would that be written?

Comment: It would be `10^(n-i:0) %*% (samp[1] , ... , samp[n])`, but I'm having trouble expressing the second row vector compactly.

Comment: I tried `10^(n-j:0) %*% samp[1:n]`, but I'm getting an error of non-comformable arguments.

Comment: Nevermind! I'm silly. I see now it's `10^(n-1:0) %*% samp[1:n]`. =]

Comment: oops, different timezones, glad you figured it out on your own :)